# PHP edit text from webpage

Tags: php

At the moment I have this:

```
<?php
$stran = file_get_contents("http://meteo.arso.gov.si/uploads/probase/www/fproduct/text/sl/fcast_si_text.html");
$stran = str_replace("<h2>","\n",$stran);
$stran = str_replace("</h2>","\n",$stran);
$stran = str_replace("<h1>","\n",$stran);
$stran = str_replace("</h1>","\n",$stran);
$stran = strip_tags($stran);

echo $stran;
?>
```

Now this gives me some empty lines at the top. I also want to delete every text after "Vir: Državna meteorološka služba RS (meteo.si - ARSO)" including empty lines before this string.

I've tried some regular expressions but the all delete all text.
Hot do I do it?

Comment: You can cut of a certain portion of the text by first determining the position of the text with strpos() and once you have that position you can slice the rest off with substr(). So something like $pos = strpos('ARSO)', $stran); $stran = substr($stran, $pos + 5);

Comment: Thanks, this works:
$stran = substr($stran, 0, strpos($stran, "Vir:"));

Comment: I would check first if $pos !== false; because otherwise it empties the string when the ARPO) is not present in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done using regex.

```
// Convert h1/h2 opening/closing tags to new line, ignore case
$stran = preg_replace('/<\/?h[12]>/i', "\n", $stran);

$stran = strip_tags($stran);

// Remove all leading whitespace
$stran = preg_replace('/^\s+/', '', $stran);

// Remove everything after "Vir: ..."
$stran = preg_replace('/(?<=Vir: Državna meteorološka služba RS \(meteo.si - ARSO\)).*/s', '', $stran);
```

Generally speaking I would recommend to really parse the html to extract the information. Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php